# How to run postgres commands in a docker container?

Tags: docker

I don't want to install postgres locally but as I have it in my docker container, I'd like to be able to run its commands and utils, like `pg_dump myschema > schema.sql`.

How can I run commands related to running containers inside of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker exec -it <container> <cmd>`

e.g.
`docker exec -it your-container /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

There are different options

1. You can actually copy files to docker using `docker cp` command. Copy required files to docker and then you can go inside the docker and run the command.
2. Make some modification in docker file for docker image creation. Its actually really simple to create docker file. Then using `EXPOSE` option you can expose a port. After that you can use docker run `--publish` ie.. `-p` option to publish a container’s port(s) to the host. Then you can access postgres from outside and run scripts from outside by creating connection.

In the first option you need go inside the containers. For that first list running dockers using `docker ps` command. After that you can use `docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash` command